# Best practice to initialize C++ components when the order is critical?

Tags: c++, dependency-management

I'm using C++ to prototype a game engine. One common task is to create a series of objects following a certain order, say object B must follow object A. The order must be enforced not necessarily because the classes are inter-dependent, but because they are hardware-related so it must follow a safety procedure of first powering up A and subsequently B.

The stylistic question is how can I ensure such an order. There is no dependency in terms of Object-oriented design, because class B doesn't require any knowledge of class A, and vice versa. So IoC is not an overkill to ensure such order requirements.

What's the C++ best practice to ensure such order dependency?

**UPDATE**: A -> B in the initialization will naturally require B -> A in destruction. Also A and B should be singletons since they are usually hardware related.

Comment: The answer can only be as specific as your question. You have an object in the dependency requirements of another. Make sure the former is constructed before the latter. *How* that happens is entirely dependent on the context of the usage and lifetimes therein (info you're privy to; we're not).

Comment: Maybe the problem is more complex than what you have described, but what stops you from initializing one thing and then the other?

Comment: I modified my question. The problem is more about initialization sequence, not dependency.

Comment: If order is critical, create a factory that builds all of your objects in the desired sequence. Exposing the factory as public and increasing accessibility restrictions of each sequential object's constructor in so that nobody can come along and randomly initialise any given object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasonable approaches to accomplishing this task. There are some unresolved questions though. First, if A must be constructed before B, then must B be destroyed before A after? Second, can you have multiples of this object? If so, is there some parameter that they must match on or something like that? E.g. imagine that the constructor to A and B both take an int, then you must construct an A(1) before you construct a B(1).

I think the absolute safest way is to embed both A and B into another class, called C. It is the safest because the standard guarantees that: 1) they will be constructed in the order of declaration in the class, and 2) they will be destructed in reverse order to that. Note that this is also automatically exception safe, unlike many potential implementations using factories.

Depending on the details of A and B's constructors, it may make more sense to have C hold the A and B objects directly, or it may make more sense to have scoped pointers. I would make sure that A and B have private or protected destructors (depending on whether you plan to allow inheritance), and declare C a friend to A and B. You can then make A and B public members of C to give easy access to their interface, or restrict things to varying degrees.

Edit: A and B should have private destructors to prevent users from accidentally deleting. For instance, if you decide to implement C as having scoped pointers to A and B, then you could get the raw pointer from the scoped pointer and call delete on it. Better this fail at compile time. In addition, the pattern I suggested is useful if you want A and B to be singletons. Since A and B both have private constructors anyway, you can just implement C as a singleton and this will take of that requirement.

Comment: Indeed, B(1) needs to destruct ahead of A(1). What's the benefit of concealing ~A() and ~B() as private?